# (DataNucleus) JDO - Service / Repository Layering and @Transactional

Tags: java, persistence, jdo, datanucleus, transactional

For personal education I am currently developing a little application framework around `Guice` to learn-by-doing how `Spring` etc. work behind the scenes.

## Intro

Just for the sake of context, here is what I have so far and plan to do so you get a feeling for what I try to archive:

**Context (Core)**

- ApplicationContext/-Configuration
- Modules (auto discovered, setting up the `Guice` bindings)

**Extensions**

- Config: `@Config`
- Locale: `@Locale` and i18n services
- Resources: `@Property`, `@Resource` and some classes providing easy access to resources
- Persistence: Problems - there we go!

## Question

I'd like to use the JDO standard (and its reference implementation `DataNucleus`) for the persistence layer. Setting up the `PersistenceManagerFactory` was easy, so was using it in a basic manner. I am however targeting a typical service / repository layer architecture, e.g.:

- Person
- PersonRepository (JDO)
- PersonService (Transactions, using PersonRepository)

That alone wouldn't be too hard either, but as soon as I tried properly integrating transactions into the concept I got a bit lost.

**Desired**

```
class PersonService {

   @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
   public Set<Person> doX() {
     // multiple repository methods called here
   }

}

class PersonRepository {

    private PersistenceManagerFactory pmf;

    public Set<Person> doX() {
        try (PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager()) {
            pm.....
        }
    }    

}
```

**Difficulties**

- `DataNucleus` supports `RESOURCE_LOCAL` (`pm.currentTransaction()`) as well as `JTA` transactions and I would like to support both as well (the user should *not* have to distinguish between the two outside the configuration). He should not have to bother about transaction handling anyway, that is part of the annotation's method interceptor (I guess).
- I'd love to support the `@Transactional` (from `JTA`) annotation that can be placed on service layer methods. Knowing that annotation is not per-se available in JDO, I thought it could be made usable as well.
- How exactly should the repository layer "speak" `JDO`? Should each method get a `PersistenceManager(Proxy)`from the `PersistenceManagerFactory` and close it afterwards (as in the example) or get a `PersistenceManager` injected (rather than the factory)? Should each method close the `PersistenceManager` (in both scenarios)? That would not work with `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transactions I guess since a transaction is bound to one `PersistenceManager`.

**What I tried**

- I have a `JDOTransactionalInterceptor` (working with `pmf.getPersistenceManagerProxy`) and a `JTATransactionalInterceptor` (very similar to https://github.com/HubSpot/guice-transactional/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hubspot/guice/transactional/impl/TransactionalInterceptor.java working with a `ThreadLocal`)

**Summary**

- I am aware that my question may not be as clear as desired and mixes the service / repository layer questions (which is my main problem I think) and transaction stuff (which I could figure out once I understand how to properly use PMF/PM in repository layer I think)
- There is no scope à la `RequestScoped` etc. I just want the first `@Transactional` method call to be the starting point for that whole thing (and that is the point: Is this impossible and the PMF/PM *have* to be scoped before and I have to direct my thinkings into that direction?)

Thanks for any clarification / help!